# Polar curve shading error with fillbetween

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So, I've tried to shade between two polar curves inside `r = 6 sin (\theta)` and outside `r = 2 + 2 sin(\theta)`. Using tikzfillbetween, I wish to only shade the crescent but it turned out the shaded area is quite abstract and not in the way I like it.

Could someone improve my code in a way that I could shade the area in Cartesian system? Hopefully could be done by using fillbetween or anything simple for me to follow.

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$,
        xtick = {-5, 0, 5}, minor x tick num = 4,
        ytick = {-5, 0, 5, 10}, minor y tick num = 4,
        xmin = -3.8, xmax = 3.8,
        ymin = -1.8, ymax = 6.8,
        font = \tiny,
        legend cell align={left},
    ]
        \addplot[name path = A, data cs = polar, orange, smooth, thin, samples = 1000, domain = 0 : 360] (x, {6*sin(x)});
        \addplot[name path = B, data cs = polar, magenta, smooth, thin, samples = 1000, domain = 0 : 360] (x, {2 + 2*sin(x)});
        \addplot[gray!20, fill opacity = .3] fill between [of = A and B, soft clip = {domain = -2.6:2.6}];
        \addlegendentry{{\color{black} $r = 6\sin\theta$}}
        \addlegendentry{{\color{black} $r = 2 + 2\sin\theta$}}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very small variation of nice @Jasper Habicht answer (+1) with wee bit shorter code, bigger font size and smaller number of samples:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$,
        xtick = {-5, 0, 5}, minor x tick num = 4,
        ytick = {-5, 5},    minor y tick num = 4,
        xmin = -6,      xmax = 6,
        ymin = -0.8,    ymax = 6.8,
        font = \scriptsize,
        legend cell align={left},
        data cs = polar, 
        smooth, 
        samples=90, 
        domain=0:360
    ]
        \addplot[name path = A, orange] (x, {6*sin(x)});
        \addplot[name path = B, magenta] (x, {2 + 2*sin(x)});
        \fill[gray!20, opacity = .3, 
              intersection segments = {of = A and B,
              sequence = {L2 -- R2[reverse]},
        }] -- cycle;
        \addlegendentry{{\color{black} $r = 6\sin\theta$}}
        \addlegendentry{{\color{black} $r = 2 + 2\sin\theta$}}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain on how does `sequence = {L2 -- R2[reverse]}` work?

Comment: @WiloryLu, the best description you can find in the package documentation. See description for `/tikz/fill between/reverse=autojtruejfalse`, pp 444 -- 446. There is stated: *Configures whether the input paths specified by of need to be reversed in order to arrive at a suitable
path concatenation.*

Comment: Could you specify the documentation title? I've searched in CTAN (got the 3.1.10 PGF Manual), but couldn't find the respective description.

Comment: @WiloryLu, sorry that name package is not explicit mentioned. Since answer is based on `pgfplots` package, I believed, that this is clear, that we talking about this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realized that earlier. Thank you very much! @Zarko

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular `\fill` command with the `intersection segments` option to draw the crescent. Also, you should probably decrease the values for `samples` in order to fasten the compilation process:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$,
        xtick = {-5, 0, 5}, minor x tick num = 4,
        ytick = {-5, 0, 5, 10}, minor y tick num = 4,
        xmin = -3.8, xmax = 3.8,
        ymin = -1.8, ymax = 6.8,
        font = \tiny,
        legend cell align={left},
    ]
        \addplot[name path = A, data cs = polar, orange, smooth, thin, samples = 250, domain = 0 : 360] (x, {6*sin(x)});
        \addplot[name path = B, data cs = polar, magenta, smooth, thin, samples = 250, domain = 0 : 360] (x, {2 + 2*sin(x)});
        \fill[gray!20, opacity = .3, intersection segments = {
            of = A and B,
            sequence = {L2 -- R2[reverse]},
        }] -- cycle;
        \addlegendentry{{\color{black} $r = 6\sin\theta$}}
        \addlegendentry{{\color{black} $r = 2 + 2\sin\theta$}}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]